# For suitable $a,b$, is it true that $(a+b) \nmid a^{m}$ for all $m \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, examples-counterexamples

Let $a,b$ be non-coprime integers; let $a > b \geq 1$. Is it true that 
$$
(a+b) \nmid a^{m}
$$
for all integers $m \geq 2$?
This seems intuitively true.
For instance,
if $a := 4$ and if $b := 2$,
then $a+b = 6$ does not divide $a^{m} = 16, 64, 256$ for $m = 2,3,4$ respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use $a=10,b=6,m>4$, then $16\vert10^m$

Comment: Thanks; a counterexample is also what I need :).

Comment: Oh, perfect, (I didn't know if it was what you were looking for). If you want more counterexamples, you can build others with powers of 2 in the same way: if $k$ is the number of digits of $2^x$ and $t$ is the most left digit, $a=t*10^k$ and $b=2^x-a$ and any power of 10 will be divisible for $m$ enough big. For example, for $512$, $a=500$, $b=12$ and $m>8$